# JavaScript within an <a> tag, nested, quote problem

Tags: javascript, quotes

Here is simple `<a>` tag, which links to an exe file. The `onClick` JavaScript event redirects the user to another webpage after 3 seconds.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/download.exe"
onClick="setTimeout('window.location="/downloading.html"',3000);return true;">
LINK</a>
```

So it doesn't work because there are too many nested quotes.

The first quotes `""` are for the `onClick` function.
The second quotes `''` are for the `SetTimeout` function.
I need third quotes for the window.location function. I've tried using both ' and " but none work. The above syntax fails.

I can solve it by refactoring the JavaScript into a function, but there are reasons why I cannot implement that. Is there a solution to this?

EDIT:

The answers below did not quite work, but led me to the correct solution:

```
onClick="setTimeout('window.location=\'/downloading.html\'',3000);return true;"
```

Comment: Can you write your code in here. So it would be easy for people to go through

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/download.exe" onClick="setTimeout('window.location=\"/downloading.html\"',3000);return true;">Something</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the inner double quote with backslash.

Here is the example:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/download.exe"
onClick="setTimeout('window.location=\"/downloading.html\"',3000);return true;"</a>
```